# binary tree implementation in php and mysql(genealogy)

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree, genealogy, mlm

I am trying to do an MLM project in PHP. Now I'm stuck on the binary tree representation of MLM. Please help me to implement the tree.[sample tree structre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNm5e.png). Please help me to build a tree-like on the attached image.

[Sample tree structre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNm5e.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can easily create a tree structure in php with function. Tree create a table or any form you can display a tree, but its best for me for displaying a mlm binary tree structure in php.

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
```

its your login id...

function tree_data($userid){

global $con;

$data = array();

$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tree where userid='$userid'");

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$data['userid'] = $result['userid'];

$data['left'] = $result['left'];

$data['middle'] = $result['middle'];

$data['right'] = $result['right'];

$data['leftcount'] = $result['leftcount'];

$data['rightcount'] = $result['rightcount'];

return $data;
}

you can easily show a tree in table format with the help of above function. like $userid your root and so..